# Frame of reference for work done against air resistance by ground vehicle

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, work, propulsion

An online cycling calculator shows power required to overcome air resistance for given wind speed and groundspeed. To cycle at 30mph in still air requires twice the power of cycling at 15mph with a 15mph headwind - the drag force to be overcome is the same, but the groundspeed is double in the first case.
This much is borne out by experience.

Why is the power equal to force times groundspeed rather than force times airspeed?

Is it because the propulsion of the bike is generated by force against the ground?

Would therefore the case of a swimmer swimming against a current, as observed from the bank, be different because they are exerting force against the ** medium ** through which they travel?

And is the guiding principal involved, stated or directly derived from any Law?

Answer (score 0):

The faster the thing you're pushing against is moving away from you, the more energy it costs to push it away with a given force. Think about a boxer who moves his head backwards to reduce the force of his opponent's punch.

The mechanical power transferred from the power source$^1$ to the rest of the system (the bulk speed of the air, the thermal internal energy of the air, bike, and road, and, if accelerating, the translational and rotational kinetic energy of the bike and cyclist), by means of the force pushing the bike, is: $$P = \vec F_1 \cdot \vec v$$

where $\vec F_1$ is the force by which the power source is transferring mechanical power $\vec v$ is the speed along the path of the force interface.

This follows from the definition of work attributable to a force, power, and velocity:

$W_{C1} = \int_C \vec F_1 \cdot d \vec r =\int_C  \vec F_1 \cdot \vec v d t $

$P = \dfrac{d}{dt} W_{C1} = \vec F_1 \cdot \vec v $

Force from wind resistance is determined by airspeed - but power still varies linearly with groundspeed.

Your online calculator is most likely treating the *bicycle plus rider* as the only power source and *the bulk motion and thermal motion of the air* as the the whole rest of the universe to which power can be transferred.

Such a treatment ignores:

- power transferred to/from the gravitational field, if the cyclist is going up or down a hill
- power transferred to thermal internal energy by rolling friction between the wheels and the road
- power transferred to/from the rotational kinetic energy of the wheels and the rider's legs, if accelerating
- power transferred to/from the translational kinetic energy of the center of mass, if accelerating
- power transferred to thermal internal energy by internal friction of the bicycle
- power transferred to thermal internal energy by stretching and contracting tissues within the cyclist himself

Comment: Thanks, "along the path of the force interface" is the detail that I could not recall seeing in any definition of work/power, though it makes perfect sense. Presumably any work done by the drag force does not form part of the cyclist's effort. The online calculator is only for constant speed, but it does include rolling resistance etc - it breaks down the power involved into each category, as well as giving the total. See www.gribble.org

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent situation goes some way to convince me that ground speed *is* the correct thing to use.

I am standing on the shore of a deep, wide lake, hauling in a boat at a constant speed of 2m/s relative to myself using a rope. The drag on the boat balances the tension in the rope. The boat travels at 2m/s through the water.

Now, I am standing on a low bridge over a deep, wide river which is flowing away from me at 1m/s , hauling the same boat towards me at 1m/s relative to myself. The boat travels at 2m/s through the water, so the drag is the same as before, and so is the tension in the rope. Clearly I am hauling on the rope only half as fast in this case, and so doing only half the work per unit time.
Is my reasoning sound?